# Get value of SPAN - Selenium-WebDriver

Tags: selenium-webdriver, html

I want to get the value of SPAN using Selenium-WebDriver. The value that I want get is this: 00000632/14

My code HTML is this:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row-fluid">
        <div class="span9">
            <div>
                <div>
                    <h3 class="subTitulo"></h3>
                </div>
                <div style="margin-top: 20px;">
                    <strong>

                        Tu número de contacto es:

                    </strong>
                    <span>

                        **00000632/14**

                    </span>
                </div>
```

Is there any method in Selenium-Webdriver to get "00000632/14" ? Thanks in advance.

Agustin

Comment: You can use absolute xpath. To get the absolute xpath you can use Firebug and Firepath on Firefox.

Answer (score 5):

If this is the **only** `<span>` element in the HTML document, then you can simply use:

```
String text = driver.findElement(By.tagName("span")).getText();
```

If you have several `<span>` elements, and you want to get the text from **all** of them, then you can use:

```
List<WebElement> spans = driver.findElements(By.tagName("span"));
for (WebElement span : spans)
{
    String text = span.getText();
    ...
}
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for your response. I have several <span> in my HTML, but i want to get only the span value of 00000632/14. When i try with the method findElements, returned me an error: undefined method `findElements' for #. I must have installed some library ?

Comment: Are you using Java or Python? For Java, download `selenium-java-2.xx.0.jar` and `selenium-server-standalone-2.xx.0.jar`, where `xx` is currently 39 to the best of my knowledge. For Python, call `pip install selenium` from a command line. Of course, you will also need to import Selenium in your code.

Comment: I'm using Rwebspec that is a gem of Ruby. Do you know the solution for this syntaxis?

Comment: @karunakarsapogu: Thanks. Tell that to OP, maybe he or she would like to accept the answer :)

Answer (score 2):

The following will work,

```
String text = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(".span9 > div > div > span")).getText();
```

Comment: Hi, thank you! I use IDE Test Wise .12.5 community. I can't use the method cssSelector because returned me an error: undefined method `cssSelector' for #. I must have installed some library ?

Comment: @user3319338 Since you are using Ruby, it's probably something like `driver.find_element({:css => '.span9 > div > div > span'})`